# Linked list not initializing

Tags: java, linked-list

I cannot get LinkedList1 to initialize, the error I am getting is "Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements. I know there are other ways to create a linked list but I want to get this way down before the others. any help would make me a very thankful coder:)

```
import java.util.*;

public class LinkedList1 {

    private class Node
    {
        String value;
        Node next;

        Node(String val, Node n)
        {
            value=val;
            next=n;
        }

        Node(String val)
        {
            this(val,null);
        }
    }

    private Node first;
    private Node last;

    public LinkedList1()
    {
        first=null;
        last=null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return first == null;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        int count=0;
        Node p = first;
        while(p!=null)
        {
            count++;
            p=p.next;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public void add(String e)
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            first = new Node(e);
            last = first;
        }
        else
        {
            last.next = new Node(e);
            last = last.next;
        }
    }
    public void add(int index, String e)
    {
        if(index<0 || index>size())
        {
            String message = String.valueOf(index);
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(message);
        }
        if(index==0)
        {
            first=new Node(e, first);
            if(last==null)
            {
                last=first;
                return;
            }
            Node pred = first;
            for(int k = 1; k<=index-1;k++)
            {
                pred=pred.next;
            }
            //splice in a node containging the new element
            pred.next = new Node(e, pred.next);
            //is theere a new last element?
            if(pred.next.next==null)
            {
                last = pred.next;
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        //use p to walk down linked list
        Node p = first;
        while(p!=null)
        {
            strBuilder.append(p.value+ "\n");
            p=p.next;
        }
        return strBuilder.toString();
    }

    public String remove(int index)
    {
        if(index<0||index>=size())
        {
            String message = String.valueOf(index);
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(message);
        }
        String element;//element to return
        if(index==0)
        {
            //removal of the first element
            element = first.value;
            first = first.next;
            if(first==null)
                last=null;
        }
        else
        {
            //to remove an element other than the first, find the pred of the element to be removed
            Node pred = first;
            //move pred forward index-1 times
            for(int k = 1; k<=index-1;k++)
                pred=pred.next;
            //store the value to return
            element = pred.next.value;
            //Route link around the node to be removed
            pred.next = pred.next.next;
            //check if pred is now last
            if(pred.next==null)
                last=pred;
        }
        return element;
    }
    public boolean remove(String element)
    {
        if(isEmpty())
            return false;

        if(element.equals(first.value))
        {
            first = first.next;
            if(first==null)
                last=null;
            return true;
        }
        //find the pred of the element to remove
        Node pred = first;
        while(pred.next!= null && !pred.next.value.equals(element))
        {
            pred = pred.next;
        }

        //pred.next==null or pred.next.value is element
        if(pred.next==null)
            return false;
        //pred.next.value is element
        pred.next = pred.next.next;
        //check if pred is now last
        if(pred.next==null)
            last=pred;

        return true;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList1 11 = new LinkedList1();
        11.add("Amy");
        11.add("Bob");
        11.add(0,"Al");
        11.add(2,"Beth");
        11.add(4,"Carol");
        System.out.println("The members of the list are: ");
        System.out.println(11);


    }
}
```

Comment: So its not not initializing but does not compile ....

Comment: tried refreshing...?

Comment: Do you think it might be helpful if you told us where in your code the error is indicated?  If you are going to ask people for help, please make it easy to help by providing basic information.  As it stands right now, the question is _"Here's 100+ lines of code, there's a syntax error somewhere, please find it"_ -- not really motivating for anyone.

Comment: You've mixed the letter `l`, and the number `1`.

Comment: @JimGarrison The error is happening in the first line of the main method. Sorry about that, first post here and thought I did an alright job but hopefully my next post wont be so bad next time:)

Comment: @Antoniossss It does not compile or initialize. The error is happening at the first line of the main method

Comment: @fgb where did i mix them up? i just looked and didnt see where i did that.

Comment: @RyanJevning You've written `LinkedList 11`, but it should be `LinkedList ll`.

Comment: @Taslim I have tried refreshing, no luck there. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

The main method has a variable name with no letters. Change 11 to tt and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`LinkedList1 11 = new LinkedList1();` 
to 
`LinkedList 11 = new LinkedList();`.